# PHP creates an not needed XML-Tag called item for a SOAP Request

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

Why does my PHP-Script output the item-Tag for each id-Element? These item-Wrapper are not needed, it gives an error on the SOAP-WS Request. I'm using nusoap.

Wrong-XML:

> ```
> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
>   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
>       <ns2475:uploadMetaData xmlns:ns2475="...">
>           <uploadMetaData>
>               <mediaNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">906</mediaNumber>
>               <associations xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="unnamed_struct_use_soapval[2]">
>                   <item>
>                       <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</id>
>                   </item>
>                   <item>
>                       <id xsi:type="xsd:string">5</id>
>                   </item>
>               </associations>
>           </uploadMetaData>
>       </ns2475:uploadMetaData>
>   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
> ```

Correct-XML:

> ```
> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
>   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
>       <ns2475:uploadMetaData xmlns:ns2475="...">
>           <uploadMetaData>
>               <mediaNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">906</mediaNumber>
>               <associations xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="unnamed_struct_use_soapval[2]">
>                       <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</id>
>                       <id xsi:type="xsd:string">5</id>
>               </associations>
>           </uploadMetaData>
>       </ns2475:uploadMetaData>
>   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
> ```

PHP-Code:

```
$associationslist = array();
foreach($xml->xpath('//associations') as $association) {        
    // add existing themes to list
    array_push($associationslist, array('id'=>$association->id));
}  
// add one after looping
array_push($associationslist, array('id'=>$themeid));
$client_mediapool->call('uploadMetaData',array('uploadMetaData'=>array('mediaNumber'=>$mediaid,'associations'=>$associationslist)), $ns);
```

Does any one have an idea?

Thank you.
Mario

Comment: Unless recent versions have made radical changes, NuSOAP's handling of arrays is distinctly wonky. Its default encoding for an array with at least one string key is to create XML elements named after the array keys, thus generating invalid XML for `array('key with spaces' => 1)`. Its default encoding for an array with all numeric keys is to assume the keys don't matter, even if they're non-sequential, and output a list of `<item>` nodes. It interoperates fine with itself, but for connecting to a 3rd-party service, you're better off using [the built-in `SOAPClient`](http://php.net/soapclient).

Comment: The reason, because I was using NuSOAP was a XML-Response with Multipart and native SOAPClient doesn't support Multipart/Related XOP. However, I've removed NuSOAP now and using SOAPClient again, but first I remove all not needed Code by extending the SOAPClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing NuSoap agian and extend the native Client helps very well.

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
{
$response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
// parse $response, extract the multipart messages and so on
//this part removes stuff
$start=strpos($response,'<soap:Envelope');
$end=strrpos($response,'</soap:Envelope>');
$response_string=substr($response,$start,$end-$start+16);
return($response_string);
}
} 

$wsdl = array();
$wsdl_url = '.../?wsdl';
$auth = 'SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC';
$login = '...';
$password = '...';
$trace = true;
$location = '.../';
$client = new MySoapClient($wsdl_url, array('authentication' => $auth, 'login' => $login, 'password' => $password, 'trace' => $trace,'location'=>$location));
```